# .gitignore for directories at a specific depth?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have directories at `components/root/js/` and `components/example/js/`, and I don't want these to be tracked by Git.

However, I have a directory `components/root/js2/plugins/js/`, which I want to have tracked by Git.

I've looked up on this online and only found `**`, which I believe does not solve my problem.

My current `.gitconfig` contains the line:

```
js/
```

I've tried changing this to:

```
components/**/js/
```

But this matches for `components/root/js/`, `components/example/js/`, but also `components/root/js2/plugins/js/` (a `js` folder below the second level of `components` - I only want to ignore `js` folders at the second level).

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Did you really mean `components/root/js2/plugins/js` and not `components/root/js/plugins/js`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Yes - basically, I don't want to sync `components/root/js`, but I want to sync `components/root/js2`, and I also want to sync `components/root/js2/plugins/js`, if that makes sense. I also want this to apply for any other directory name in between, for example, `components/abcd/js2/plugins/js`.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I follow - if you added `components/root/js/` and `components/example/js/` to your `.gitignore` what stops `git` from tracking files in `components/root/js2/`? It's not a subdirectory of ignored directories.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It doesn't track `components/root/js2/plugins/js/`, because that directory is also called `js`. I want it to track that, though - only `js` directories that are two levels down from `components` shouldn't be tracked.

Comment: Can't you simple literally add `components/root/js/` and `components/example/js`? Can you show us your current `.gitconfig`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk There's about 20 or so different directories, so I was wondering if a dynamic solution is possible. I don't have a `.gitconfig` file, do you mean `.gitignore`?

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, how about this:

```
js/
!components/root/js2/plugins/js/
```

It will ignore all directories called `js` except for ones specified after `!`. In such scenario `git` will ignore `components/root/js/` but won't ignore `components/root/js2/plugins/js/`.

`**` won't work because as it's said in `man gitignore`:

> A trailing "**" matches everything inside. For example, "abc/**"
>   matches all files inside directory "abc", relative to the location of
>   the .gitignore file, with infinite depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `.gitigore` files in any directory which will be a more reliable solution if the directories are moved later.

I would create 2 `.gitignore` files:

- One at the project root `/.gitignore` which excludes `js`

  js
- One in the `plugins` directory `/components/root/js2/plugins/.gitignore` which overrides root `.gitignore`

  !js

If the `plugins` directory will be moved later, e.g. to `components/root/plugins` the `.gitignore` will be moved too.

If you configure everything in the root `.gitignore` you must not forget to edit the root `.gitignore` if the directory is moved.